Error when trying to use "includes() function
Trying to loop through req.files and get sort files by their name and store them in the corresponding columns in my database which are equal to the file name. but for some reason on my second else if statement the includes function says that the req.files.key.name property is undefined.
const postDocs = (req, res) => {
    for (let key in req.files) {
        if (req.files[key].name.includes('additional documents')) {
            // Code for handling additional documents
            const fileData = req.files[key].data;
            const query = 'INSERT INTO uw_action_documents (additional_documents) VALUES (@fileData)';
            const request = new db.Request();
            request.input('fileData', db.VarBinary, fileData);

            request.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return res.status(500).send('Failed to store file in the database');
                }

                console.log('File stored successfully in the database');
                res.status(200).send('File stored successfully');
            });
        } else if (req.files[key].name.includes('endorsements')) {
            // Code for handling endorsements documents
            const fileData = req.files[key].data;
            const query = 'INSERT INTO uw_action_documents (endorsements) VALUES (@fileData)';
            const request = new db.Request();
            request.input('fileData', db.VarBinary, fileData);

            request.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return res.status(500).send('Failed to store file in the database');
                }

                console.log('Endorsements file stored successfully in the database');
                // Note: You may want to send a different response for endorsements files
                res.status(200).send('Endorsements file stored successfully');
            });
        }
    }
};


The error you're encountering, where req.files.key.name is undefined likely stems from the way you're accessing the req.files object. When iterating over req.files using a for...in loop, key will be a string corresponding to the name of the file field in the form. However, req.files[key] is expected to be an array or an object, depending on how files are uploaded and the middleware you're using (like multer, express-fileupload, etc.). This is why directly accessing req.files[key].name can lead to issues if req.files[key] is not structured as expected.
To resolve this issue, first, ensure that you're using appropriate middleware for file uploads in Express.js. Libraries such as multer or express-fileupload are commonly used for handling multipart/form-data, which is necessary for file uploads.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Try using forEach to iterate over the files if you have formatted to accept an array instead.
req.files.forEach((file) => { }
